# CVS support in Domino Designer

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

Internally we already have set up a CVS server, for all our Java developers.
Is there a way to use this CVS server from within the Domino Designer.
Should it be possible with the SVN connectors? Or are there any other connectors required?

Comment: I'd highly suggest you look at a different Source Control solution. CVS is fairly outdated, modern DVSC solutions like Git and Mercurial will give you a lot more power and functionality.

Comment: Yes I know, but internally we have CVS already in place. It is a start to get feeling with Source Control, also for the other Domino devs. In the future we drop a request to install a 'real' Source Control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the CVS Team Plugin to your Domino Designer environment. As CVS is part of the core Eclipse platform you'll need to use the main Eclipse 3.4 updatesite as the source and then select just that plugin. This will then give you the CVS team options.

the updateSite you need to add is http://download.eclipse.org/releases/ganymede/ and you just need to add the CVS client under the Collaboration category.

Comment: Declan, you are the king. I have installed the plugins and restart DDE. After some playing around in some perspectives I was able to commit the code to CVS

Answer (score 1):

The other 2 options you will need to enable are "Eclipse Help System" and "Eclipse Platform" which are under the Enabling Features for both top level categories.  After installing all the plug-ins you must restart designer to provide the CVS Client option under Team in preferences.